# Entity Framework with Owin DbContext per request in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, owin, dbcontext

I noticed the project template for MVC when using individual user accounts puts a few objects in the current Owin context (in `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs`):

```
// Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

It looks like this is to access the database for Identity features. My understanding is that a single instance of `ApplicationDbContext` is created per request and re-used through the entire pipeline. Would it be beneficial to do the same with my own entity framework `DbContext`s?

For example I created a new file in `App_Start/Startup.Data.cs`:

```
public partial class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureData(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.CreatePerOwinContext(CreateParkingEntities);

    }

    protected ParkingEntities CreateParkingEntities()
    {
        return new ParkingEntities();
    }

}
```

Then in `Startup.cs`:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        ConfigureData(app);
    }
}
```

Then I can use the context in my controllers:

```
private ParkingEntities _db;

public ParkingEntities DbContext
{
    get
    {
        return _db ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ParkingEntities>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _db = value;
    }
}
```

I would think if this was standard practice, the entity framework would have some scaffolding for this, but it just creates an instance at the controller level.  Is it safe to assume that if `DbContext` is only accessed from that controller then it would be functionally equivalent to the above implementation and placing it in the Owin pipeline is overkill?

I suppose another use of this approach is a single initialization point for the DbContext, if additional setup is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DbContext` is designed to be lightweight, so there isn't much cost to creating a new instance every time you need one. The main costs are re-creating the connection and garbage-collecting all of the instances you are creating.

Note that if you use the `Find()` method on the DbSets, it will cache the result, so next time you ask for it, it doesn't need to go to the database. If you re-use the same context, you can take advantage of that cache, but if you create a new context, you lose the cache.

If you store the `DbContext` in an instance member of the controller, then it will only get used for one request, since a new instance of the controller will be created for each request. Just make sure you DON'T put it in a static member - I expect that you would get all kinds of race conditions if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

The main approach to use EF db-context is simple: connect to the db-context, get your data and forget about this db-context object. EF context is IDisposable and closes the connection after dispose (don't forget about using(){}). It means, that you can create EF data-context anywhere in your application when it needs a db-connection. You can create new db-context right inside the controller-action if they are using your db. Everything depends on what is the architecture of your application. If you are sure, that all requests to your app will need many db-operations, I think your solution with db-context per owin-context can be useful.

Comment: Any reasoning why the Identity system chose to do it this way?